# prevent api from being called before state is updated

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have a list of objects. I want to make an api call once the location field of the object is changed. So for that, I have a useEffect that has id, index and location as its dependencies. I have set a null check for the location, if the location isn't empty, I want to make the api call. But the thing is, the api is being called even when the location is empty, and I end up getting a 400. How can I fix this and make the call once location isn't empty?

```
    const [plants, setPlants] = useState([
        {
            name: 'Plant 1',
            id: uuidv4(),
            location: '',
            coords: {},
            country: '',
            isOffshore: false,
        }
    ]);
    const [locationIDObject, setlocationIDObject] = useState({
        id: plants[0].id,
        index: 0
    });

    const handlePlantLocChange = (id, index, value) => {
        setPlants(
            plants.map(plant => 
                plant.id === id
                ? {...plant, location: value}
                : plant
            )
        )
        setlocationIDObject({
            id: id,
            index: index
        })
    }

    const getCoords = (id, index) => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3002/api/coords', {
            params: {
                locAddress: plants[index].location
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            if(response.status === 200) {
                handlePlantInfoChange(id, PlantInfo.COORD, response.data)
            }
        })
    }

    const handler = useCallback(debounce(getCoords, 5000), []);

    useDeepCompareEffect(() => {
        if(plants[locationIDObject.index].location !== '')
            handler(locationIDObject.id, locationIDObject.index);
    }, [ locationIDObject, plants[locationIDObject.index].location])

    return (
        <div className='plant-inps-wrapper'>
            {
                plants.map((item, idx) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={item.id} className="org-input-wrapper">
                            <input placeholder={`${item.isOffshore ? 'Offshore' : 'Plant ' + (idx+1) + ' location'}`} onChange={(e) => handlePlantLocChange(item.id, idx, e.target.value)} value={item.isOffshore ? 'Offshore' : item.location} className="org-input smaller-input"/>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: Your null check should be directly before the `axios.get` (i.e. it should be within `getCoords`). Also, doing `!== ''` is not the same as a null check.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I sometimes use null check to refer to when a string is empty, I should probably get this bad habit fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the issue was with my debouncing function. I don't know what exactly the issue was, but everything worked as expected when I replaced the debouncing function with this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("it changing")
        const delayDebounceFn = setTimeout(() => {
            getCoords(locationIDObject.id, locationIDObject.index)
        }, 4000)

        return () => clearTimeout(delayDebounceFn)
    },[...plants.map(item => item.location), locationIDObject.id, locationIDObject.index])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your useCallback is not updating when value of your variables is changing and that is the issue:

Although the check is correct, but the call is made for older values of the variable. You should update the dependencies of your useCallback:

`console.log(plants)` inside `getCoords` might help you investigate.

Try this:

```
 const handler = useCallback(debounce(getCoords, 5000), [plants]);
```

Comment: adding plants in the dependencies of my useCallback just caused my input value to keep mutating on its own, and getCoords was never called. Still, thanks for the help tho, it's because of you I changed my debouncing function